# how to fix , selenium.webdriver.Chrome() , tracebook

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

> > > selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "C:\Users\madhu reddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
> > > self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
> > > File "C:\Users\madhu reddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
> > > self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> > > File "C:\Users\madhu reddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
> > > hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> > > FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in 
selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
File "C:\Users\madhu reddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\madhu reddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Answer (score 0):

In the first error, it says that `Python` can't find the file, make sure the file exist, or try to use double `/` instead.

---

Second, You need to download a [driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for Chrome in order to run the JavaScript engine. Once you download it, you need to provide the full path to it or add to your PATH variable in your system.

I can see that you are using Windows, so [How to set a new variable in PATH?](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Will automatically find the webdriver executable
```